# Bug Python 2.7.7 VS 2.7.9 on Debian Wheezy

Tags: python, debian, apt-get

I wanted to install Python 2.7.9 on my Debian Wheezy and I've download the .deb file from Debian site. Unfortunately now I apparently have caused a bug, this is what I have after an apt-get upgrade:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2.7 : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-6+deb7u2) but 2.7.9-2 is installed
 python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.9-2) but 2.7.3-6+deb7u2 is installed
             Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.9-2) but it is not installable
 python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-6+deb7u2) but 2.7.9-2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

If I try an `'apt-get -f install'` it asks me to remove more than 2GB from my OS and I don't want this. Any idea?

Comment: you included the text twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this way: as basically the problem was

```
python2.7 (= 2.7.3-6+deb7u2) but 2.7.9-2 is installed
```

I've downloaded python version `2.7.3-6+deb7u2` and with a simple `dpkg -i` I have installed it. The downgrading as been automatic

Answer (score 0):

The right way when working with distributions such as Debian is two work with the official repositories, that is, using `apt-get install` rather than downloading and installing with `dpkg -i`.

If you work directly with `dpkg`, important information that `apt` needs is missing.

My suggestion for you is this-

1- Undo you changes by using `dpkg -P` on the package you installed manually

2- Run `apt-get update`

3- look for the package with apt- `apt-cache search python=<version>` or without version.

4- If you don't find the wanted version, you can use other official Debian repositories (include them in you apt sources list files)

Comment: dpkg -P not working; but dpkg --configure libpython2.7 gives:

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython2.7:
 libpython2.7 depends on python2.7 (= 2.7.3-6+deb7u2); however:
  Version of python2.7 on system is 2.7.9-2.

dpkg: error processing libpython2.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpython2.7

Comment: Is there any way to downgrade Python to the previous one?